# Are equivalent fractions in a set considered distinct elements?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

(1) In set theory, set A{1, 2, 2} is equivalent to the set B{1, 2}. So, for example, the product of all the elements in set A is 2, and the product of all the elements in set B is 2. Correct?

(2) Is the set {1/2, 2/4, 3/6} equivalent to the set {1/2}? What about to the set {.5}?

(3) Is the set {.6-repeating) equivalent to {.6-repeating, .66-repeating, .666-repeating} (where the repeating digit is the final digit listed in each instance)?

(4) Is the set {.6-repeating} equivalent to the set {.$\overline{6}$}? Are either of those equivalent to the set {0.$\overline{6}$}?

(5) Is the set {(1+2)} equivalent to the set {3}?

I ask because I ran into a math question that considered {1/2} and {2/4} to not be equivalent sets due to 1/2 and 2/4 being "distinct" fractions. But I viewed those fractions merely as different ways of representing the same quantity, just as 0.$\overline{6}$ and .$\overline{6}$ are, or 1/2 and 0.5 are. What's the convention here and can we always count on it being followed consistently across text books and tests etc?

This was NOT a question about statistics, by the way. It was strictly about how many elements end up in set C after combining the elements from sets A and B (where set A contains 1/2 and set B contains 2/4).

Does context matter? For example, whether we're representing quantities strictly speaking versus representations of quantities; just as {(the man with the stick)} has one element wherein {(the man with the stick), ("the man with the stick")} has two elements: the actual man with the stick and the sentence that represents the man with the stick: i.e., "the man with the stick."

Comment: I believe your understanding is 100% correct. Context does matter. Really the definition of set equality is one and the same (two sets are equal if every element of the first set belongs to the second set and vice versa), but the context comes to play when you need to decide if two elements are the same or not. In your example, it should've been clear from the context that they are planning to treat $1/2$ and $2/4$ as different fractions.

Answer (score 2):

In all of these questions (1), (2), (3), (4) and (5), if you are talking about subsets of $\mathbb R$, the set of real numbers, then in each case the sets are the *same*, the are *equal*.

In your question (1), the sets $A=\{1,2,2\}$ and $B=\{1,2\}$ are not only equivalent, they are *equal*, they are one-and-the-same mathematical object. The reason for this is that in set theory, $A=B$ if and only if for all $x$, the statements $x \in A$ and $x \in B$ are equivalent. This is true for the sets $A=\{1,2,2\}$ and $B=\{1,2\}$: $1 \in A$ and $1 \in B$ are both true; $2 \in A$ and $2 \in B$ are both true; and if $x$ is any number other than $1$ or $2$ then $x \in A$ and $x \in B$ are both false.

Similarly, in your question (2) all of the sets are equal to each other, because all of the elements are equal to each other: 
$$\frac{1}{2} = \frac{2}{4} = \frac{3}{6} = .5
$$

And the same continues to hold for your remaining examples.

You can see a pattern here, perhaps. We can have different expressions, different "names", for the same number. The two expressions $\frac{1}{2}$, $\frac{2}{4}$ are not identical, but they represent one-and-the-same real number.

You might keep in mind: a binary operation, like division, inputs a pair of real numbers and outputs a real number. So, for example, if the input to division is the pair of numbers $1,2$ then the output is equal to $\frac{1}{2}$, and if the input is the pair of numbers $2,4$ then the output is $\frac{2}{4}$ which is equal to $\frac{1}{2}$. Different inputs can give equal outputs. Perhaps that is what your math question was referring to: thinking about the inputs as different, rather than the outputs which are equal.

Answer (score 1):

What numbers *are* is different from how we *write them down* with particular symbols.

"$1/2$" and "$2/4$" and "$3/6$" are all ways to write down *the same element of $\mathbb Q$*, and a set that consists of only that element is the same sat no matter how we write it (or even if we *don't* write that element explicitly, such as if we're speaking about something "for all sets that consist of exactly one rational number").

This same element of $\mathbb Q$ can also be written "$0.5$" or sometimes "$.5$". Using decimal representations do not change what it is we're speaking about *mathematically* (though it *may hint* that the speaker might be considering the number to be an approximation of a nearby "truer" number -- but that is not universally the case).

Likewise, "$0.\overline 6$" or "$0.66\overline{66}$" are ways to write the number we can also write as "$2/3$". Writing ".6-repeating" is somewhat rare, but it should pretty universally be understood as yet another way to write that particular number.

And yes, when "$(1+2)$" appears in a mathematical expression, we recognize it as a reference to the number more commonly written as "$3$". It is the number of things you have when you have one thing more than one and one thing.