# Does the set of rational numbers include repeating values?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, rational-numbers

In my Discrete Math lecture, we were told that we should omit any number that repeats in the set of rational numbers $\mathbb{Q}$. In other words, we should only keep $\frac{1}{1}$ and omit $\frac{2}{2}, \frac{3}{3}$, etc. But I don't see why this would be the case, since the set is defined as $\mathbb{Q} = \{\frac{a}{b}|a,b\in\mathbb{N}, b\ne 0\} $ Does the set $\mathbb{Q}$ include these repeating values?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos link is sufficient. If it also helps, you can also attach the addendum to your set that $\gcd(a,b) = 1$ if that makes you feel better.

Comment: Not exactly. Sure, the elements are the same value wise, but that's only if you choose to simplify each element. If you don't, then would you technically have distinct elements $\frac{1}{1}, \frac{2}{2}, \frac{3}{3}$?

Comment: "*the elements are the same value wise*"  Yes.  They are the same... so even if we wrote them multiple times that would just be redundancy.  The set $\{1,1,1,1,1,2\}$ is a two-element set.  It is equal to the set $\{1,2\}$.  Whether we were redundant or not, we only ever consider something to "*be in*" the set or "*not be in*" the set.  There are no alternatives and there is not a concept when it comes to *sets* about "being in a set multiple times"

Comment: The value of an element does not depend of the way you write it. $\frac11=\frac22.$ A rational number $\frac ab$ is not an ordered pair $(a,b)$.

Comment: After looking around with some different wording, this post answers my question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3346612/are-equivalent-fractions-in-a-set-considered-distinct-elements. @AnneBauval answered the question in the same way.

Comment: Now... if you wanted to be more formal... you should be defining $\Bbb Q$ as the quotient ring $(\Bbb Z\times (\Bbb N\setminus\{0\}))/\simeq$ where $\simeq$ is the equivalence relation $(a,b)\simeq (c,d)\iff ad = bc$.  We choose to write $\frac{a}{b}$ rather than $(a,b)$ for aesthetic purposes.  Since $\Bbb Q$ is a quotient, the elements are technically equivalence classes.  Your saying $\frac{1}{1}$ is an element of $\Bbb Q$ is more accurately saying that $[\frac{1}{1}]$ is an element of $\Bbb Q$, and indeed $[\frac{1}{1}]$ is equal as a set to $[\frac{2}{2}]$

Comment: Keep in mind that, for example, $\{\frac{1}{2},\,\frac{2}{4},\,\frac{3}{6}\}=\{\frac{1}{2}\}$. It does not matter how many times you list an element in a set, it can only be in the set once. Either it is in the set or it is not in the set. There is no other option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a nice question. You see, when we build the set $\mathbb{Q}$ we do not only define the elements in form, there is an additional definition of "equality".
Let $x=\frac{a}{b}$ and $y=\frac{c}{d}$. We say that
$$x=y\Leftrightarrow ad=bc$$

So in fact, the set of rational numbers is the set
$$\left\{\frac{a}{b}\vert a\in \mathbb{Z}\wedge b\in \mathbb{Z}^\ast\right\}$$
after we identify i.e. "glue" the equal numbers together.